How to generate Liquibase changelogs with Quarkus using the Liquibase Hibernate extension?
I'm working on a Java application using Quarkus and I'm trying to generate Liquibase changelog files from my JPA entities. Previously, I have successfully used the Liquibase Hibernate extension with Kotlin and Spring Boot to achieve this. Here's a brief overview of what I did with Spring Boot:

Added Liquibase Core and the Liquibase Hibernate 6 extension to my project.
Configured Liquibase in my build.gradle.kts (URL, db user and password, ...).
Used the diff command to generate a new changelog file containing the diff between my entities and the referenced database.

How can I achieve similar functionality in a Quarkus application?
Here is what I have done so far in my Quarkus project:

Project Setup:

Created a new Quarkus project.
Added the following dependencies in pom.xml:

<dependencies>
  ...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
    <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-liquibase</artifactId>
    <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate6</artifactId>
    <version>4.28.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>


Added and configured the Liquibase Maven plugin:

<plugins>
  ...
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.28.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <driver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver>
      <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/ORCLCDB</url>
      <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/db.changelog-master.yaml</changeLogFile>
      <username>foo</username>
      <password>bar</password>
      <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:com.example.myapplication?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect&</referenceUrl>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>

Note: I know I am using the Hibernate Spring connection URL, but I don't know which other Hibernate URL I should use.

Liquibase Configuration:
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=oracle
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=${DB_HOST:jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/ORCLCDB}
quarkus.datasource.username=${DB_USER:foo}
quarkus.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD:bar}
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=none
quarkus.liquibase.migrate-at-start=true


Defined my JPA entities. For example:
package com.example.foo.repository;

...

@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    // Getters and setters
}



However, I haven't found a way to generate the Liquibase changelog files from my JPA entities within the Quarkus ecosystem, like I did with Spring Boot.
Is there a way to generate Liquibase changelog files from JPA entities in Quarkus using the Liquibase Hibernate extension, or is there an alternative approach I should consider?

Have you looked at Generate Liquibase diff changelog using Liquibase maven plugin in Quarkus

Yes, unfortunately, I keep encountering the following error:
[INFO] Error getting default schema java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.CallableStatement.executeQuery()" because "cs" is null
After debugging, I discovered that Liquibase is attempting to access the entities in my code through a "schema," treating my code as if it were a database.

There is no direct way of doing this, but answer is it's tricky but yes you can achieve it. It's not very neat but close to a working solution.
You can also check certain discussions in Quarkus Github as well as Liquibase-hibernate issues here and here
In my ecosystem I use gradle.
configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
    liquibase
    liquibaseRuntime.extendsFrom runtime
}

ext {
    diffChangeLogVersion = "CHANGE-0002"
    rollbackTagVersion = "CHANGE-0002"
    diffChangeLogFile = "src/main/resources/XXXX/db-changelog-${diffChangeLogVersion}.oracle.sql"
    entitiesPackage =  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
    hibernateGenericDialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"
    springCoreVersion = "6.1.2"
    springDataVersion = "3.2.1"
}

dependencies {
    // Liquibase
    implementation "io.quarkus:quarkus-liquibase"
    liquibaseRuntime "org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate6:4.30.0"
    //liquibaseRuntime "org.liquibase:liquibase-groovy-dsl:3.0.2"
    liquibaseRuntime "info.picocli:picocli:4.7.5"
    liquibaseRuntime "com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc11-production:23.2.0.0"
    liquibaseRuntime "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1"
    liquibaseRuntime "ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.9"
    liquibaseRuntime "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.9"

    liquibaseRuntime "org.springframework:spring-core:${springCoreVersion}"
    liquibaseRuntime "org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:${springDataVersion}"
    liquibaseRuntime "org.springframework.data:spring-data-envers:${springDataVersion}"
    liquibaseRuntime sourceSets.main.output
}

task deleteDiffChangeLog(type: Delete) {
    delete diffChangeLogFile
}

task liquibaseEntitiesToDbDiffChangelog(type: JavaExec) {
    dependsOn deleteDiffChangeLog
    group = "liquibase"
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    classpath configurations.liquibaseRuntime
    mainClass = "liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine"
    args "--logLevel=FINE"
    args "--changeLogFile=${diffChangeLogFile}"
    args "--url=${dbURL}"
    args "--username=${dbUser}"
    args "--password=${dbPassword}"
    args "--defaultSchemaName=${dbSchema}"
    args "--driver=${dbDriver}"
    args "--referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:${entitiesPackage}?dialect=${hibernateGenericDialect}"
    args "diffChangeLog"
}


Thank you for your answer, it pointed me in the right direction: It turned out I was missing the Spring Framework dependencies. After adding them, Liquibase was able to successfully create the changelog file.
As a side note: In my original question, I mentioned using the Hibernate-PostgreSQL driver, but that was a mistake on my part due to a copy-paste error. The correct driver for my use case is the Hibernate-Oracle driver.
